# Missing author ; Missing updated in google web master tool

Tags: php, wordpress

I got the missing author and missing updated error in my site. So I have added the following funtion in my funtion.php. It resolved the missing author and missing updated error in all posts but the error still alive in home page. How to resolve it. Please help me.

```
function add_suf_hatom_data($content) { 
    $t = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
    $author = get_the_author();
    $title = get_the_title();

    if (is_home() || is_singular() || is_archive() ) {
        $content .= '<div class="hatom-extra" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;"><span class="entry-title">'.$title.'</span> was last modified: <span class="updated"> '.$t.'</span> by <span class="author vcard"><span class="fn">'.$author.'</span></span></div>';
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'add_suf_hatom_data');`
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is referring to the author and last modified **meta tags**. You should add them to your `<head>` of every page. For example:

```
<meta http-equiv="last-modified" content="YYYY-MM-DD" />
<meta name="author" content"Someone" />
```